# How to get Offset , partition and timeStamp values of ConsumedRecord in KafkaStreams (KStreams)?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm consuming **avro message using genericRecord** .

```
final KStream<String, org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord> kStream = streamsBuilder
                .stream(topicName, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),genericAvroSerde));
```

I need to get the **offset value , partition value and timeStamp of consumed record** . So , could anyone please guide me on how to get those values .

Thanx for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get these values using Kafka Steams DSL.

The Processor API, however, can

https://kafka.apache.org/32/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorContext.html